# Javascript document.cookie = "key=value" appends instead of replacing

Tags: javascript, string, cookies

Came across this syntax of adding new key in cookie on a browser:

```
document.cookie = "key=value";
```

which appends this value in `document.cookie` instead of replacing the old value which is the operation it should be doing in default scenario.

How is this string behavior achieved i.e. over-riding the default operation?

Comment: It should only replace the 'key' and leave any other key/value pairs there. Is it not changing the key?

Answer (score 1):

This is how cookies in JavaScript have always worked.

```
document.cookie = "key=value";
document.cookie; // "key=value"

document.cookie = "key=value2";
document.cookie; // "key=value2"

document.cookie = "key2=valuex";
document.cookie; // "key=value2;key2=valuex"
```

The original `key` is only overwritten if it is specified again. Cookies are weird and counter-intuitive because regardless of how many cookies for the domain are set, there is only ever one value for `document.cookie` - a single string

Comment: My question is on your last operation document.cookie = "key2=valuex"; . Intuitively, after this operation document.cookie; should output only "key2=valuex" i.e. replacing the older value instead of appending in the string. How is this achieved?

Comment: If it uses a unique key, which in this example it does, it will add it as a "new" cookie (a new part of the cookie string). To overwrite an existing "cookie" (i.e. an existing key in the cookie string), the key must be the same. In the above example, the second assignment to `document.cookie` overwrites the first one because the key is the same